# e-mail validation happening despite required: false,

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation plug-in. I want to keep email optional and want to validate it only if we type in the field. I have tried required: false, in rules but validation is still happening. Please help.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("customemail", 
            function(value, element) {
                return /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i.test(value);
            }
        );

    $( "#signupForm" ).validate( {
            rules: {
email: {
                required: false,
                customemail: true 
            },
messages: {
email: {
                customemail: "Please enter a valid e-mail address",
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a bit like as below:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customemail", function(value, element) {
        if ($("#email").val().length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ($("#email").val().length > 0) {
            return /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i.test(value);
        }
    },"Please enter a valid e-mail address");
```

and remove required: false from your validation rule as well as customemail: "Please enter a valid e-mail address" from the messages.

$("#email").val() - make sure id is the same as input id

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi... tried changing the code to this one but no luck.

Comment: Check the value of value.length. what are you getting in it?

Comment: value.length used as >0 as suggested but still it is validating

Comment: Or is it because of the message which is defined for customemail? thanks

Comment: On submission of form, without filling any data in email field I am getting the error message.

Comment: hi, try the code I have changed. if it is still not working put alert(value.length) before if(value.length > 0) and let me know the value.

Comment: hi, please see my update, now this should work as expected. let me know